# JavaScript confirm window

Tags: javascript, confirm

I am reviewing some code around a JavaScript confirm call. From my understanding, confirm [returns true or false](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp). The developer I am working with keeps doing the following:

```
function askTheUser(question, myCallback) {
  var result = confirm(question);
  myCallback(result ? 2 : 1);
}
```

The line that is throwing me for a loop is the `result ? 2 : 1`. Why would someone do that instead of just `myCallback(result);`

Is there something related to callbacks that I'm not aware of. I'm just interested in returning the true or false associated with whether a user confirmed the question or not. I keep looking at it. It just looks incorrect.

Thank you.

Comment: We can't tell you why it's important to convert `true/false` into `2/1` without more context.

Comment: In this case, when the user presses OK, it returns `2`, otherwise it returns `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result ? 2 : 1` means that if `result` is true then 2 is returned otherwise 1

He/She must have a special reason to do so. Try looking the code where it's being used.

Answer (score 1):

It's not *incorrect*, it's just converting `true/false` into `2/1`. Presumably they have some reason for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right. It should just be (result). The callback can then assign 1, 2 or whatever it wants - if its really necessary to do so!
It is simply going to invoke the callback with the parameter, there's nothing special about it

Comment: To the down-voter, as part of a code review I think its important to question the use of arbitrary numbers, and to keep things logical and simple. So yes- use the original bool value!

Comment: +1'ing you for the "it *should* be and don't use arbitrary numbers", but if you are going to make this point could you edit to make that more clear in your answer what "should" means?  You can wish an interface to be something other than what it is, but you don't always have the executive authority to change it.